# How to review images between two different projects

Tags: php, laravel

ّI have couple Laravel projects one in name`students` I will put it in an independent domain while the other project in name `teachers` should be in another domain. If the student have to upload images in `students` project how can the teacher review the images from the other project `teachers`? Is it possible to put a mutual folder for both projects ?

Comment: Do you run both projects on the same server?

Comment: Of course you can. Hell, you can even have them in different platforms. But maybe this question is more about twerking the config of apache/xampp/whatever server you have

Comment: yes they are in same server

Answer (score 0):

If both projects are on same server then you can create symlink. That will be helpful. Because images will be available in both sides

```
ln -s students/public/uploads teachers/public
```

As I think this is the easy solution.